# Change sections name in QHeaderView

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtreewidget

I use a QTreeWidget to display multicolumn items, and I want to have a header with column names. However, I only get numbers, as shown in this screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Here is a piece of my code, which should do it (but does not):

```
class BugsList(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, reports):
        super(BugsList, self).__init__(parent) # Call QDialog constructor
        # ...
        self._tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)
        self._tree.setColumnCount(4))
        header = QtGui.QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        header.addActions([QtGui.QAction(x, header) for x in ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')])
        self._tree.setHeader(header)
        # ...
```

Regards,

Valentin Lorentz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with using setHeaderLabels().